# Flask decode data

Tags: python, flask, request, decode

I have this API:

```
@app.route("/api/flask/market/calculate", methods=['GET'])
def get_test_calculation():
    print(request.args.get("company-data"))
    return request.args.get("company-data")
```

This API is called by a SpringBoot server request which has attached JSON.

It seems to return data in the form:

```
%5B%7B%22id%22:1,%22companyName%22:%22Apple%22,%22marketType%22:%22Technology%22,%22country%22:%22USA%22,%22priceChange%22:%22 1.5%25%22
```

How do I decode this string to get rid of the %22 etc to format into JSON.

Thanks

Thanks to Jim Wright for pointing me in the right direction. This worked:

```
import urllib.parse
url_decoded = urllib.parse.unquote(url_encoded)
company_data = json.loads(url_decoded)
```

Comment: can you please show your sample url for this request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In @jackabe's case it seems that the JSON data is being sent as a URL encoded JSON string.

To decode the JSON company-data from a query parameter the following will work as long as the JSON is properly formatted (@jackabe's example is missing the closing `}]`).

```
import json
import urllib

@app.route("/api/flask/market/calculate", methods=['GET'])
def get_test_calculation():
    url_encoded = request.args.get('company-data')
    url_decoded = urllib.unquote(url_encoded).decode('utf8')
    company_data = json.loads(url_decoded)
    print(company_data)
    return company_data
```

In your example your query parameter is actually not a valid JSON string.

```
import urllib
t = '%5B%7B%22id%22:1,%22companyName%22:%22Apple%22,%22marketType%22:%22Technology%22,%22country%22:%22USA%22,%22priceChange%22:%22 1.5%25%22'
decoded = urllib.unquote(t).decode('utf-8')
print(decoded)
```

Output (missing the closing `}]` or `%7D%5D`):

```
[{"id":1,"companyName":"Apple","marketType":"Technology","country":"USA","priceChange":" 1.5%"
```

In Python 3 you should do the following to decode the var:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
decoded = unquote(t)
```

Comment: you need do a POST as well, generally get is for getting information and post for send information to the service

Comment: I have a separate server which is performing the GET request

Comment: I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' for body

Comment: @jackabe change your API to POST instead than get and when you call it do it with a POST instead than GET

Comment: Module 'urllib' has no attribute 'unquote', are you using Python 3?

Comment: FYI I did not output the full JSON string, it does open and close with }]

Comment: Updated to include the correct unquote function for python 3 :)